# How to remove double white space character using regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Input:

```
".    .   .  . ."
```

Expected output:

```
". . . . ."
```

Comment: best way to learn is to just do it, try http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ for testing

Comment: [Regular Expression Pocket Reference, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514273?green=13581578926&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596514273.IP) is a pretty decent book. Nice and handy in your back pocket (If you got sweet programmer jeans).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
text = text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

- `\s` will take all spaces, including new lines, so you may change that to `/ {2,}/g`.
- `{2,}` takes two or more. Unlike `\s+`, this will not replace a single space with a single space. (a bit of an optimization, but it usually makes a differance)
- Finally, the `g` flag is needed in JavaScript, or it will only change the first block of spaces, and not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
result = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="this is    some text    with   lots  of    spaces!";
var result =str.replace(/\s+/," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

in PCRE:

```
s/\s+/ /g
```

in JavaScript:

```
text = text.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Comment: I wonder who voted me down.
And what is wrong with my answer?