# jQuery to reflect user input as the type, in a separate div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a textbox called `names` that allows a user to enter individual words, each word separated by a space.

I then have a `div` called `preview` which contains nothing initially, but with each character that appears in the `names` textbox, I'd like to show this in the preview div, with each individual word (based on 'space' seperation) to be output as individual span tags (so I can then apply a style to each individual 'name' within the preview.

I should also mention that in some scenarios, values will be arriving in the `names` textbox via a jQuery UI Autocomplete list (which I've already got working), and also pre-filled (when I'm editing a record for example and prefill the textbox with previously chosen names).

My jQuery isn't great and I've had a look around for a solution, but not had much success.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just take all the text from the `names` textbox and populate it in the preview div at each key-stroke unless performance becomes an issues.

```
$('#names').bind('keyup', function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var tokens = text.split(" ");
    var output = "";
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
       output+= "<span>"+tokens[i]+"</span>&nbps;"; //note extra space at the end
    }
    $('#preview').innerHTML=output;
});
```

Comment: Sorry this will only work when typing. You can changing the binding to `focus` or just add a second binding on the `textarea` for `focus`. that way when the field does in fact focus the update will happen.

Comment: Thanks Ali - this works great, except for the last line which I had to change to: $('#preview').html(output); for it to display. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Just a couple things that I've noticed. 1) If the user enters a load of spaces, it outputs individual spans with a single space inside, which ideally I'd like to avoid/not output single spaces inside spans. 2) I mentioned the textbox is sometimes populated via jquery autocomplete - in that scenario, when i select an item from the autocomplete list, it doesn't update the preview div until I press a key (or give the field focus/blur) - any suggestions?

Comment: there is a regex method to remove double white spaces from a string, you could use that to solve the extra space problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609080/how-to-remove-double-white-space-using-regexp 
As for the selecting from jQueryUI, have you tried binding on `change` instead? I'm not sure if it'll detect javascript updates but if it does that could solve your problem, otherwise I can't think of anything other than a tweak to the jQuery plugin.

Comment: There is one other solution, the div that the jQueryUI create from which you select your autosuggest feature, you could bind a mouseclick call on that. So something like `$('#dynamicDiv').bind('mouseclick', function(){ myTextParsingFunction(); //or trigger the change event for the input field $('#names').change() });`

Comment: OK, the selecting from autocomplete menu is now sorted, thanks to your comment. I just assigned the same function as you put above, to: $(".ui-corner-all").click(function () {... I've also implemented the regex as mentioned in the other SO question that you linked to and it sorted everything except for if I put a space at the very beginning of the textbox, then it renders an empty span - if I then backspace to remove the space char in the textbox, the empty span remains? So close, just this last little niggle left... any ideas? I tried using a .trim() on the var text = $(this).val()

Comment: All you need to do is trim the ends, just call `jQuery.trim()` on the text variable http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/
Perhaps you aren't using the trim function properly. If an empty string is being read then put the for loop inside an if condition and make sure the text variable length > 0. Though I don't think this should be necessary but then again maybe on an empty string the split method returns an array of 1. so `text = $.trim(text); if(text.length() > 0) { ...}`

Comment: @marcusstarnes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2368/discussion-between-ali-and-marcusstarnes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.. create a javascript function which is called every time when user press some key on textbox field.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $("#names").keypress(function() {
        populateWord('keypress');
    });

    //blur function is to fix the bug, because last word may not contain space in the end, and we only want to perform update when textbox loose focus and word may or may not end with space       
    $("#names").blur(function() {
        populateWord('blur');
    });

    function populateWord(type){
        val = $("#names").val();
        var gotLetter = false; //to avoid word which contains only space in loop back lookup
        //we first check if we got a space then it means we got a word
        if((val[val.length-1] == ' ' $$ type == 'keypress') || type == 'blur'){
           var word = '';
           for(var i= val.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
               if (val[i] == ' ' && gotLetter){
                  //we got the last entered word
                  //now append it to preview div
                  $("#previewDiv").append("<span>"+word+"</span>");
                  break;
                }
           else{
                word = val[i]+word;
                if (val[i] != ' '){
                   gotLetter = true;
               }
             }
           }
        } 

    }

</script>
```

Comment: The benefit of using this script is that you dont have to loop over all present words you just need to collect last entered word and then update the preview. it is better in terms of performance also (i think).