# AJAX to show text that you type

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a one textarea's on my page which is located on the left. On the right side I have a simple div.

The textarea will later become CKeditor. Now I would like to have it so that when I type something in the textarea, that it immediately displays the text I'm typing in the div.

I just notices that Stackoverflow uses exactly what I wish to have. While I write this question I get to see what it will look like below.

How exactly is this done? I've searched on Google and followed AJAX tutorials but I'm not getting tutorials that get me closer.

Thanks!

Comment: You are searching it wrong. It's a javascript and DOM topic, not PHP and AJAX :)

Comment: [This recent post][1] I contributed towards has your answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023682/jquery-to-reflect-user-input-as-the-type-in-a-separate-div/7023730#7023730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no AJAX in this situation. Just JavaScript processing. You set up a change event handler on the input item (textarea or other) and with JS you format that text and put the formated content inside another container.

AJAX would require server requests, while this is done entirely on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#text-area-id').keypress(function() { $('#div-id').html($(this).value()); });
```

this can probably help:)

if you are not using jquery then you can do this

create method which will be called on key press

```
function onChange(el)
    {
       document.getElementById('#div-id').innerHTML = el.innerText;

     }
```

then attach event on your textarea

```
<textarea onkeyup="onChange(el);"></textarea>
```

Comment: -1 for assuming jQuery... It's clear that he's a novice in this field. He won't understand anything from your code.

Comment: what it means -- assuming jQuery?

Comment: IIRC, the `change` listener only fires when you lose focus on the field. The OP could theoretically use jQuery, though, Alin.

Comment: @munjal: Senad's answer relies on using jQuery. OP didn't mention anything about using jQuery or any other library.

Comment: @munjal He assumed that asker uses and is familiar with the jQuery JavaScript framework. That is neither stated, nor implied anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This does not relate to ajax. It's just a javascript challenge. First, you have to have a js function that handle the [keydown event](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/jss3p3.html) of the textarea, then you will change the text value (or html value) in the right div in responding to the keydown event. I think that you should learn more about javascript then jquery for easily solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code from a recent quesiton that needed something similar. I'm guessing you know enough JS to modify it as per your needs.

```
$('#names').bind('keyup', function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var tokens = text.split(" ");
    var output = "";
    for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
       output+= "<span>"+tokens[i]+"</span>&nbps;"; //note extra space at the end
    }
    $('#preview').innerHTML=output;
});
```

The original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023682/jquery-to-reflect-user-input-as-the-type-in-a-separate-div/7023730#7023730).

Comment: What is up with all your guys and jQuery? At least if you want to suggest a jQuery solution put a link to it and explain what's what.

Comment: A simple google search should explain what jQuery is. If you are a coder the code should make sense. All it does it for the given `input`/`textarea` element, on `keyup` it takes the value of the input element, splits it into an array of words using space as a delimited puts a span around each word and write the html out into a `div` with the id `preview`. jQuery javascript lib reduces the code you have to write and provides a lot of convenience functions, if you dont want to use it, just use `document.getElementById()` and attach an event listener (instead of bind) example http://goo.gl/RMjT

Answer (score -1):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").keyup(function(){
        $("div").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxf8x/