# How to remove double spaces in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

It's the same with [How to remove double white space character using regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609080/how-to-remove-double-white-space-using-regexp)

but for vb.net

how to do so?

Comment: `str = Regex.Replace(str, "\s+", " ");` - is this what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim text = "My         name      is          Anas                 Fares"
Dim newText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "[ ]{2,}", " ")
```

Or this one if you want to get rid of TABS, NEWLINES etc etc etc.

```
Dim text = "My         name      is      " & Environment.NewLine & "    Anas                 Fares"
Dim newText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "\s+", " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You would simply do a string replace on a double white space, to a single white space:

```
Dim str = "Lorem  Ipsum  Dolar"
str = str.replace("  ", " ")
return str 'Lorem Ipsum Dolar
```

But you could still use the same regular expression in VB.NET as used in the javascript code from your link. This article shows a way of doing just that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

```
Dim input As String = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + _
                            "whitespace."
Dim pattern As String = "\s+"
Dim replacement As String = " "
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)

Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input)
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result)
```

Answer (score 3):

A direct conversion would be:

```
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("\s{2,}") 'or " {2,}" or "[ ]{2,}", depending on if you want whitespace, or just spaces.
Dim stringWithDoubleSpaces As String = "this  is  a double  spaced  string"
Dim stringWithSingleSpaces As String = r.Replace(stringWithDoubleSpaces, " ")
```