# How to remove the white space before a word in a sentance in JS

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a sentence like below,

```
var text  = 'My       name         is           Ran';
```

I wnat this text to print like below,

```
'My       name is              Ran';
```

I want to remove the space before 'is'.Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove double white space character using regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609080/how-to-remove-double-white-space-character-using-regexp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163169/replace-multiple-whitespaces-with-single-whitespace-in-javascript-string)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981349/regex-to-replace-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635952/javascript-how-to-remove-all-extra-spacing-between-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated for:** *Hi Ramesh ,how can I replace only the space before 'is', if my string is `My name         is           Ran;`*

```js
var  data='My name         is           Ran';
var  result = data.split("is");
console.log(result[0].replace(/ +/g, ' ') +"is" + result[1]);
```

### For the OP Update 2

```js
var  data= 'My       name         is           Ran';//
var  result = data.split("is");
var  result1 = data.split("name");
console.log( result1[0]+  "name " + "is" + result[1]);
```

### Final Solution by the OP question update 5th

```js
   var  data= "My       name     is           Ran";// or My       name  is           Ran

   if(data.indexOf("name   ") == -1)
   {
      var  result = data.split("is");
      var  result1 = data.split("name");
      console.log(result1[0]+  "name " + "is" + result[1]);
   } else   {
      var  result = data.split("is");
      var  result1 = data.split("name");
      console.log(result1[0]+  "name " + "is" + result[1]);
   }
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh ,how can I replace only the space before 'is',if my string is

Comment: var text = 'My name         is            Ramesh';  o/p should be

Comment: @TNTR Okay I have updated my answer for your 3rd update. I hope you not update the question anymore.

Comment: But I am not sure that 'name' is always there but 'is' will be there always.

Comment: Then check the condition for `if(str.includes("world   ")){}else{}`

Comment: @TNTR I have update my question. don't forget to mark as an answer. Bye

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace method with second parameter one space.

```js
var text  = 'My name      is  Ran';
var newString = text.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
console.log(newString);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = text.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
```